# Intellij-idea need to make and build xx.war every time when template changed?

Tags: java, spring, debugging, intellij-idea

I am new to java and spring mvc.
Because of good impression for pycharm, I choose IntelliJ Idea as my java IDE.
After some searching, I set up a debug configuration using tomcat.But I found  I must make and build xx.war every time when template(.jsp file) changed , or I wouldn't see any changes in frontend .
I have never seen such situation in pycharm(python django project debug) and visual studio(.net mvc3 debug).
Is this java have to be?Or I can change some config to avoid remake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

1. open your Tomcat Run/Debug configuration (Run > Edit Configurations)
2. Go to the "Deployment" tab
3. In the "Deploy at Server Startup" section, remove (if present) the
   artifact `xxx:war`.
4. Click the add icon, select 'artifact' and then select `xxx:war exploded`

Then,in the Run/Debug Configuration Window, select the "Server" tab, "Update resources" or "Update Classes and Resources" will display in `On 'update' action` and  `On frame Deactivation`.

- Update resources: All changed resources (that is, all application components other than the classes) will be updated.
- Update classes: and resources. All changed resources will be updated; changed classes will be recompiled. Note that whether the actual classes will be updated depends on the capabilities web server. If I recall, Tomcat will reload html/xhtml and jsp files, but not Servlets or classes that JSPs or Servlets use. You need to modified Tomcat to use a dynamic classloader for that.

For me who just change template to select `Update resources` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to remake and redeploy every time you make a change. However, this is primarily a tomcat question, not an intellij question.

First, you have to deploy an exploded war (you should have that option when you choose which files to deploy in the tomcat configuration box in intellij). Then you have to configure tomcat to scan for changes to jsps and recompile them. I don't know which version of tomcat you're using but you can find documentation on that on the tomcat site, or questions about achieving it here on SO.

That will only take care of the jsps though. With an exploded war static resources, such as css and javascript, should be immediately accessible after a change. It's only the need for tomcat to recompile the jsps that is causing your problem.

Comment: I'm using tomcat 7.0, I found document about [jasper]:`http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html`(I don't know how to add link in comment).It seems that I should add a `<project ...>` block in web.xml and replace the `${webapp.path}` with a certain project path.How can I make it work to all project in Intellij-idea??